# Do I need ob_end_flush(); in my PHP logout scripts?

Tags: php

I have `ob_start();` at the beginning of my "signin" file and everything works fine. I can sign up, sign in and sign out.

However, I don't have `ob_end_flush();` anywhere in my code and it works fine without it. When I do put it in my code ( in the sign out file right behind `session_destroy();` ) it makes the sign out process a lot slower.

Can someone with a little more experience tell me a little more about this `ob_end_flush();` and why it's necessary?

Comment: It's good practice, but not necessary.

Comment: It depends. If you're not outputting anything there you don't need the ob_start either.

Comment: Are you confusing session and output buffering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ob_start and ob_end_flush are used to capture the output buffer so that `echos` and the like will only output if and when you want them to.

This is often handy when you have pages that may, or may not have a `session_start`.  Being that you can't send the headers required for a session_start *after* you have output anything else.

By controlling when the output buffer is sent to the client you can delay the sending until you are sure that you've sent any headers you want.

Some might say that good software architecture and design means you shouldn't need to buffer to cover this case - but that would be opinion, and there are plenty of other examples where this makes sense anyway.

However, the output buffer will still be flushed when the process ends regardless of if you "end" it.

This means if you start with an `ob_start`, but never `ob_end_flush`, the output should still be flushed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't want everything to be buffered. For example:

```
ob_start(function($c) {
    return "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($c)."\" />";
});
imagepng($someimage);
ob_end_flush();
```